A sufficient condition for P-matrix
Following the terminology of Parthasarathy (1983), a matrix is a $P$-matrix if every principal minor is positive. He shows that a matrix with the positive dominant diagonal property ($b_{ii} > \sum_{j\ne i} |b_{ij}|$ for every $i$) is a $P$-matrix.
My problem is the following: I have a block matrix in which any 2×2 block on the primary diagonal has 3 positive large numbers, and one off-diagonal element (say, the top right) is precisely zero. The elements in the off-diagonal blocks are very small in absolute terms relative to the 3 positive elements in the diagonal block.
Any ideas on formulating (and proving) a claim for P-matrix in this case?

I think this is very false. Probably there is a counterexample already with $4\times 4$ matrices

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Edited, thanks!

edited my answer

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is a block matrix with $2\times 2$ blocks with all diagonal blocks equal to identity, and thus $P$-matrices, and all off-diagonal block singular, and thus with determinant zero.
It is not a  $P$-matrix because its determinant is negative.

For your new question: this has still negative determinant
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
1000 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 10 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 10 & 10
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thanks, that's very helpful. I should have seen it. In my actual problem, any 2×2 block on the primary diagonal has 3 positive large numbers and one off-diagonal element (say, the top right), which is precisely zero. The elements in the off-diagonal blocks are very small in absolute terms. So, I guess the second condition can be that each of the three "large" elements in each diagonal block is larger than the sum of the other elements in their row (outside the diagonal block). If you have more thoughts about it, it will be much appreciated, thanks again

I have edited the question following your comment (hope it is ok)

You are right again, of course. Thank you! What if we add another condition that the sum of each column is zero (if it helps, the sum of odd rows as well as the sum of even rows in each column is zero)

@Muly if the sum of each column is zero, then the matrix is singular and thus it cannot be a P matrix

Right. Sorry for the silly questions, and thanks for your help. Will try again in the future...
